# Invalidate parent page cache when children get updated

Tags: sulu

I made a page structure like this:

- Parent Category page

  - Child Page 1
  - Child Page 2

The parent page use `{% set pages = sulu_navigation_tree(uuid) %}` to get a list of children page. From that i'm looping over `pages` to show each child in a "gallery" way.

The problem is that when i add a child in the admin, the parent cache page is not invalidated, so the website do not know about the new child that was added.
I have to manually click on the "Refresh website cache button" at the top at the top of the admin webspaces page.

Is there something to do to avoid this button click, and the cache to be automatically refreshed ?